# Copied Laravel project getting 500 server error

Tags: laravel

I copied a laravel project including all of its recursive file permissions. Then I loaded it to a sub domain on plesk server. I installed all the dependencies using plesk's application interface. I was getting an error regarding the cipher and key so I changed the app_key to SomeRandomStringWith32Characters. I also am getting an error when I run artisan saying " PHP fatal error: uncaught reflection exception: class log does not exist in /var/www/vhosts/domain/subdomain/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:1291". then it lists the stack trace listing #0-4.

Additionally I have configured the .htaccess file in my public folder to look like this

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
#For REST support
       Allow from all
 </Limit>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase / # <------------ This one you missed

    #Just to redirect to www.site.com when only site.com comes
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
    #end of codes

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am new to laravel so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Check your config files for custom logic that may be attempting to execute before the associated dependencies have been loaded by the IoC (through service providers).

Comment: Did you run `composer install` at the server? Did you create a new env file for this server?

Comment: @user2094178 I did create a new .env file for the server. I didn't run composer install through ssh until this morning when it returned that my php version was 5.3. I ran the composer and laravel install through plesk web interface. And plesk also shows im running php7.0.19. When i try to invoke php7 through /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php composer install, the error I get says could not open input file composer

Comment: You could download `composer.phar` and run `/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php composer.phar install`

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all the cached files in both bootstrap and storage directories. Run the following:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and

```
php artisan env
```

you may want to run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

as well

Comment: i'm not able to run any artisan commands because of the stated errors in my question. Strangely i was able to run composer dumpautoload successfully though

Comment: Composer is not dependent on the Laravel software stack so it shouldn't be interfered with.  Delete everything in bootstrap/cache directory first and try running artisan commands again.

Comment: I removed the bootstrap/cache directory tried running php artisan config:cache but i get the same "class log does not exist in..." error that i was getting.